# I'm popular in Mexico

Tags: riddle, word

> I'm popular in Mexico.
>   But if you mix me up, you'll find me more often in Canada.
>   With a small addition, I'm found around both, and in between.
>   Mix me up again and I'll be at your throat.
>   Another addition, and I'll be at the game.

What am I?

Comment: Not Donald Trump?

Comment: @fi12 Honesrly was my first thought

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I'm popular in Mexico

> taco

But if you mix me up, you'll find me more often in Canada.

> coat

With a small addition, I'm found around both, and in between.

> coast

Mix me up again and I'll be at your throat.

> ascot - @moose

Another addition, and I'll be at the game.

> mascot - @moose

Comment: Yeah, it was a pretty easy one I guess.  Looks like this answer beat the other one by approximately a minute, so I'll award this one.

Answer (score 15):

Building on the partial answer:

I'm popular in Mexico

> taco

But if you mix me up, you'll find me more often in Canada.

> coat

With a small addition, I'm found around both, and in between.

> coast

Mix me up again and I'll be at your throat.

> ascot (as in the tie)

Another addition, and I'll be at the game.

> mascot

Comment: Correct, but slightly too slow.  It was a close one though.

Comment: Haha indeed, wouldn't have got there without rlord's answer.  Unfortunately don't have commenting privileges yet, and had to figure out how to type spoilers too!

Comment: @Shagnik Pro Tip (I'm serious): Post your answer ASAP with bad formatting then immediately edit it to improve. You'll get the initial votes and time stamp advantage :-)

Comment: @Insane Thanks for the tip, I'll keep that in mind :)